# <input> type="submit" not posting to action

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working with a templated html bootstrap theme and for some strange reason my submit button is not posting. I can't seem to figure out why. The template came in pure HTML so what you see here is me adding some MVC to it.

**View**

```
<!-- Heading -->
@model JDMXCHANGE_SITE_ACCOUNT.ViewModels.AccountController.AuthenticateViewModel
<h2>Registration</h2>
<!-- Sign Up Form Start -->
@using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.Name)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.Name, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Name" })
            @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.Email)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.Email, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Email" })
            @*<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email">*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.ZipCode)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.ZipCode, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Zip Code" })
            @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="zipCode" placeholder="Zip Code">*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.Username)
            @Html.TextBoxFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.Username, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Username" })
            @*<input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Username">*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.Password)
            @Html.PasswordFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.Password, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Password" })
            @*<input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">*@
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.AcceptTermsAndConditions)
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(P => P.RegistrationViewModel.AcceptTermsAndConditions) Accept terms and conditions
                </label>
                <span class="pull-right"><a href="#">View</a></span>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group text-center">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <input type="submit" value="Register" name="ActionRegister" class="btn btn-black"/> &nbsp;
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**ViewModel**

```
 /// <summary>
/// Holds the registration and login viewmodels since the login/register/contact functionality all reside in the same view. [Authenticate]
/// </summary>
public class AuthenticateViewModel
{

    /*NOTE: The classes contained by this class are redundant so that each redundant property has it's own attributes. We do not want to enforce regex on usernames
     if they are only loging on and not registering etc.*/



    public RegistrationViewModel RegistrationViewModel { get; set; }
    public LoginViewModel LoginViewModel { get; set; }
    public ContactUsViewModel ContactUsViewModel { get; set; }

    public AuthenticateViewModel()
    {
        this.RegistrationViewModel = new RegistrationViewModel();
        this.LoginViewModel = new LoginViewModel();
        this.ContactUsViewModel = new ContactUsViewModel();
    }

}

public class ContactUsViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email address.")]
    [Remote("CheckEmailAvailability", "Account", ErrorMessage = "This email already is registered.")]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(3000, ErrorMessage="Maximum amount of characters allowed is 3000")]
    public string Comments {get; set;}
}

public class RegistrationViewModel
{
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [StringLength(14, MinimumLength = 6, ErrorMessage = "Must be between 6 & 14 characters long.")]
    [RegularExpression("^[A-Za-z]{2,}[_-]?[A-Za-z0-9]{2,}$", ErrorMessage = "Only alpha-numeric characters and one '-' or '_' allowed.")]
    [Remote("CheckUsernameAvailability", "Account")]
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [StringLength(14, MinimumLength=6, ErrorMessage="Must be between 6 & 14 characters long.")]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage="Not a valid email address.")]
    [Remote("CheckEmailAvailability", "Account", ErrorMessage="This email already is registered.")]
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage="Not a valid email address.")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.PostalCode, ErrorMessage="Invalid zip code.")]
    [Display(Name="Zip code")]
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid zip code.")]
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Accept terms and conditions")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage="You must accept the terms and conditions.")]
    public bool AcceptTermsAndConditions { get; set; }
}

public class LoginViewModel 
{
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Remember me")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

**Action**

```
   [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(ViewModels.AccountController.AuthenticateViewModel _model)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);

                // For more information on how to enable account confirmation and password reset please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Send an email with this link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirm your account", "Please confirm your account by clicking <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">here</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                AddErrors(result);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

What is strange is if I do not input anything into the form and try to submit it, I get all the correct validation messages for each input field. If I put in all the required data and hit submit, nothing happens. I sniffed the network and I saw my remote validation was working correctly but when I hit the submit button nothing shows up on the network sniffer. Also, if I try to submit the form without checking the "Agree to terms and conditions" check box, I do not get a validation message back for it, which I should be getting. Last time my post was failing was due to some model binding error that was failing silently, but I can't seem to see any possible sources for error either.

Comment: do you have any partial view in the main view? If yes, then check if the partial view has some library added

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "check if the partial view has some library added" ?

Comment: I am talking about jquery libraries, you don't need any additional jquery libs.You know that